# Two circle intersection

Tags: circles, quadratics

Two circles intersect at two points maximum when we want to draw intersecting circles. But there we are solving quadratic equations, what is the argument about the other two missing points?

Comment: Which points, do you think, are missing?

Comment: Too hand-wavy to post as an answer perhaps, but the geometric "intuitive" argument is worth noting: Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two distinct circles. Their points of intersection must be collinear. Suppose by way of contradiction that their points of intersection contains a non-collinear subset. A non-collinear set of points has at least three points. But three non-collinear points determine a unique circle, contradicting the assumption that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are distinct. So the points of intersection must be collinear. Since a line intersects a circle at most at two points, so too do two circles.

Comment: Can you tell me what are all the 4 points. Two are intersection points, then what are the other two points.? Thank you.

Comment: Well, 2 circles can intersect at infinite points.

Comment: I realize that I just marked this as a duplicate of a _later_ question. Reason: both questions are from the same user, who re-asked the same question with one detail added for clarification. The later question is what this question _should_ have been edited to, and appears to have a more complete answer, so it makes more sense to refer to the later question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the centers of the circles are $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and $(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$. Notice that-

1. The line joining the intersection points must be perpendicular to the line joining the points $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and $(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$.
2. The line joining $(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$ and $(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ must also pass through the midpoint of the line segment joining the intersection points.

There are at most two distinct points satisfying the two conditions.

Comment: There are at most two points that is right. But "Hence although we get 4 points in total" can you tell me what are the other two points? thank you.

Comment: I didn't thought over the other two points, though but it seems that eliminating any one variable from the equation will result in a biquadratic equation of the remaining variable. Suppose, I eliminate $x$ then we will get a biquadratic in $y$ and hence four values of $y$. Now for each values of $y$ we get only one value of $x$ which satisfies both the equations. Hence $4$ points.